# Pattern of Swiss Valor number

Tags: untagged

I'm trying to find the exact specification about the Swiss Valor number pattern.
Is there even a pattern or is it just an increasing number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valoren_number) to the rescue:

> #### Allocation Methodology
>
> The VALOR number is a numeric code that intrinsically has no meaning.
> When a new VALOR is needed, the next one from the list is simply
> allocated. An instrument's number indicates nothing about the
> instrument itself.

Comment: But is there a minimum or maximum length?